# How to get parameter from angular with $routeParams

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, routeparams

I want to get some posts by category id. So I need to get a parameter from URL in angular but somehow it seems the route does not call the right controller when I put `:id` as the parameter in the `category` route. Here is the controller looks like.

```
.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: "home.html",
                    controller: "mainController"
                })                    
                .when('/category/:id', {
                    templateUrl: "category.html",
                    controller: "categoryController",
                });
    }])
```

And this is the controller.

```
.controller('categoryController',['$scope','$http','$ionicModal','$routeParams','$location', function ($scope, $http, $ionicModal,$routeParams,$location) {

        var id = $routeParams.id;

        var httpUrl = 'http://localhost/myapp/';

        var url = httpUrl + 'webservices/get_posts_by_category?cat_id=' + id;
            $http.get(url).then(function (result) {

                console.log(result);

                $scope.posts = result.data;

            })
```

But it shows nothing, event it doesn't fire the `console.log(result)`. Looks like it routes to the wrong controller. I just don't know why. What did I miss?

Comment: Please provide code from where you call category page.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing right url to get method? Try to log that url in console and check.

Comment: @Rahi.Shah I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Do you mean where I call `categoryController` in view with ng-controller?

Comment: No, I mean that you call category page from somewhere give that file of code because first, you have to check that you call category by proper link address because you said that it routes to the wrong controller.

Comment: @Rahi.Shah ahh, I see and I know the issue. I call the page from an link with `href=#category`. I change it to `href=#category/{{page.id}}` and it works. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: Welcome and please upvote the comment.